Make sidebar links (e.g. "example newsletter") look different than plain text, as before
Links in sidebar boxes (e.g. "example newsletter" in "Love this site?" or "writing great tag wikis" in "What are Tag Wikis?") look exactly the same as the text around them. Spot any difference between "see an" and "example newsletter"? The latter is a link, the former isn't, but there's no way to tell except by my cursor changing on hover. The link's color doesn't change on hover or after visiting it.

<p id="newsletter-preview-container" class="mt8 mb0 ta-center">
    see an <a href="/digest/preview" id="newsletter-preview">example newsletter</a>
</p>

Linked text used to be a different color, but perhaps that got lost in July along with other sidebar design issues.

This issue is distinct from Links should not look the same as plain text as that focused on links in comments, and is site-design-specific. In e.g. the default beta theme (example), usernames which have links are colored differently than those which aren't links (due to the profile being deleted).
Please at least restore the previous behavior of using a different color for links. Maybe even throw in an underline while you're at it, since links shouldn't be differentiated based only on color.

Technically it's a bug, as links must be different according to all the rules I know, and according to  common sense, plus it used to be fine until they just removed it. But since it was done on purpose as part of design changes, it means the bug is in the very core of their design, not implementation. Might have still tagged it as bug, but over time realized it's quite meaningless anyway.
